# Trying to install Speakker HTML5 audio player

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, html

I'm working on a dev site (http://bit.ly/HuLCn1) for a podcast.  Above the contact form on the right, I'd like to add in an HTML5 audio player -- preferably the one found at http://www.speakker.com which slides up.  Does anyone have experience with this player?  No matter what I do, I literally CANNOT replicate the player found on the developer's main page, even though there are instructions.  Wondering if there's something I'm missing here?

Also, if anyone knows of any other nice HTML5 audio players, I'm open to suggestions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are three JS errors on your page, including a missing brace. You should fix them first.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have three javascript errors and you're loading two copies of the main jQuery 1.4.2 library. Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox, or in Chrome or Safari or IE8, use the developer tools to see what's loading on your site and see the JS errors.

Second, you need to correctly enqueue scripts in Wordpress so you don't duplicate scripts (either core scripts for your theme and scripts that plugins will load via `wp_head`) and load scripts according to their dependancies. Wordpress also includes many jQuery libraries, so you don't have to also include them in your theme. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Third, you're using Thesis. Try switching to twentyeleven with the same plugin and see if you have the same JS errors and if the audio player works. That means a conflict JS in Thesis and possibly a doc type error, too, if Thesis doesn't use a html5 doc type.